# Error 404 on browser when console says "Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ "

Tags: python, flask

The browser shows a 404 error even though the Flask application is running on localhost on the same port. What could be missing?

- Windows 10
- Python 3.7.6

I have set the virtualenv and run

- Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

I have activated the bat file

- env\scripts\activate.bat

```
(env) PS G:\Flasktut> set FLASK_APP=app.py
(env) PS G:\Flasktut> flask run
  * Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
  * Debug mode: off
  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2020 15:24:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
(env) PS G:\Flasktut> flask run
  * Environment: production
    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
    Use a production WSGI server instead.
  * Debug mode: off
  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2020 15:32:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

My code for app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/')

def index():
    return 'hello world'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please share your `app.py` file in the post.

Comment: try to show us what you have tried

Comment: from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/')

def index():
    return 'hello world'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)

Comment: This is my first tutorial app and I am stuck right here

Comment: Hi, try set  to turn on debug mode app.run(debug=True). This can help debug the error,  Best

Comment: set FLASK_APP=app.py(debug=True)
debug=True : The term 'debug=True' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

flask run(debug=True)
debug=True : The term 'debug=True' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Could there be a configuration error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.route('/')

def index():
    return 'hello world'
```

You forgot the `@` before the `app.route('/')` line.

Flask's [`route`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.route) is not a regular function call, but a decorator. Check the [Quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) tutorial again from the Flask docs. It is used to "attach" a URL rule/path to a specific function, in this case the `/` path (`http://127.0.0.1:5000` + `/`).

It should be `@app.route('/')`.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I will check the route and decorator concept. Thanks a lot

Comment: @YuvrajMetrani Generally, 404 errors mean a particular URL path is not hitting any of the `route`-function pairs.